# In Symfony, How to iterate over the data returned by doSelect?

Tags: symfony1, iterator, propel

In Propel ( using in Symfony ), I am using the following:

$data = ObjectPeer::doSelect($myCriteria); // $myCriteria is Criteria Object

How can I iterate over the $data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess:

```
foreach ($data as $object)
```

Comment: foreach ($data as $object){

echo $object->getAbacusTitle();// assuming abacusTitle is a field name
}